# Chart.JS: Show custom labels permanentely on doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can I show custom labels permanently in a Chart.JS doughnut chart using `chartjs-plugin-datalabels`?

The example looks now like this:

[image]

Under https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/formatting.html#data-transformation, I found that the following code should change the labels to custom formatting:

```
formatter: function(value, context) {
    return context.dataIndex + ': ' + Math.round(value*100) + '%';
}
```

Why doesn't this work in the example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o4kyt69j/1/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I didn't read properly...

Here's the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/o4kyt69j/2/

The code should be:

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            formatter: function(value) {
                return value + " kWh";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to use this only with Chart.JS versions > 2.7.0 (Another mistake I made before).